# Running flutter using python flask

Tags: python, flutter, flask

I'm working on a flutter project and I used python for back-end. I want to run the flutter code from my python file using `os.system()`. But before that I want some line code that should be executed before the `os.system()`. But the problem this command always run first. Is there a way to make it wait until the code is executed and then it will be running the last one or is there a another command that do the same work. Or can I make a condition in my case to let it wait.Any help is highly appreciated.

This is my code :

```
import json
import linecache
import os
import glob
import subprocess
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET']) 
def foo():
# write into .text.txt    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json     
        json_object = json.dumps(data)        
        files = glob.glob('var.json')
        for f in files:
            os.remove(f)
        with open('var.json', 'a') as file:
            file.write(json_object)
        envdata = json.load(open('var.json'))    
        files = glob.glob('.env')
        for f in files:
            os.remove(f)
        f = open(".env", "a")
        for key, value in envdata.items():
            f.write(f"{key.upper()}={value}\n")
        os.system("flutter run")       
    return "hello world"
    # run flutter to generate ios and apk using run methods process to run flutter app from python flutter build apk / flutter build ios. I can do it
    # zip ios and apk
    # send zip to client using email adres    
if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe the case that the line you want to run before is a async task and that's why the os.system gets executed before it. You can add "await" keyword before the line -

```
await "the async line"
os.system("flutter run")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using a async task

Comment: what is the line you want to run?

Comment: The three line before the os.system() are not working before the os.system().  f = open(".env", "a")
        for key, value in envdata.items():
            f.write(f"{key.upper()}={value}\n")

Comment: I add a time.sleep(10) before the os.system() and it worked is this correct ?

Comment: You know the word in the dev world - "working code is correct code" . Well it will work but if sometime the for loop or the three lines took more than that time then it will stop working again.... You can do a thing call the os.system inside the for loop with a condition check as such it gets called on the last iteration of the loop. That will work in all cases.